# What is the most suitable error message if the Request Body is missing from a POST request?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest

What is the most suitable error message and status code if the Request Body is missing from a POST request? And should there be an error message that should be displayed?

Comment: I'd use [422 Unprocessable Entity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422).

Comment: @sp00m Should there be an error message that should be displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

400 Bad Request would be the most suitable. Because missing a body is just sending a bad request. Unfortunately there isn't a 4XX (client errors) code that says "Request Body Not Found"

Comment: should there be an error message that should be displayed?

Comment: With stuff like error messages you should always be descriptive and concise about the message, but the more valuable information on how the error occurred the better. Its always recommended to use your own error messages along with the built in ones as it can only help you in the long run.

Comment: If something is missing from the body then 400 is the right response code, whereas a requested resource that is not found is a 404. An error message is always nice to let your users know what they have done wrong